# Combine two matlab plotting commands to execute loops

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, plot, contour

I am a new user in matlab, i have two separate commands and would like to combine them so as to produce figures in a loop with a specific pause

these are the two separate approaches

1. Create the base figure from A , A2, A3 , ... An

   ```
   who Hsig*
   filenames = who('A*')
   for i=1:3
      pause(2);contourf(eval(filenames{i})),colorbar
   end
   ```
2. Second portion is to superimpose a quiver with B, B1, B2 ....N and C,C2,C3,...n

   ```
   nx,ny]= size(A)
   xx=1:1:ny; 
   yy=1:1:nx; 
   pause(2);contourf(eval(xx,yy,A)),colorbar
   hold on
   delta = 8;
   quiver(xx(1:delta:end),yy(1:delta:end),B(1:delta:end,1:delta:end), ...
   C(1:delta:end,1:delta:end),1)
   hold off
   ```
3. I tired to combine them but i think i am missing something, probably the eval ?

   ```
   filenames = who('A*')
   B10 = who('B')
   C10 = who('C')
   for i=1:3
      [nx,ny]= size(A)
      xx=1:1:ny; 
      yy=1:1:nx; 
      pause(2);contourf(eval(xx,yy,filenames{i})),colorbar
      hold on
      delta = 8;
      quiver(xx(1:delta:end),yy(1:delta:end),B10{i}(1:delta:end,1:delta:end), ...
      C10{i}(1:delta:end,1:delta:end),1)
      hold off
   end
   ```

Any help is welcome

Comment: A best practice when debugging is to try and replicate the issue with as few lines of code as possible or as simple as possible. This could help highlight where the problem is for you as well as help people like me dive in and help, you just have a lot of excessive code to dig through honestly. I am also not sure what you mean by "combine".

Comment: @Shaun314 use these two different commands to generate a figure(s) and will have as its base the countourf while the quiver is overlapping it, for every different dataset available

Comment: What is it doing now? Is it drawing the contour and quiver in the same figure window overlapped but not for each dataset? Are you wanting a different figure window for each dataset? The contour is what is changing and you want to impose the same quiver over it each time?

Comment: @Shaun314 yes its drawing the quiver over the contour on the same figure, and i want to extent these procedure to multiple files. Each file of A, B, C represent a different timestep and the correct contours and quiver be applied

Answer (score 0):

just an update after reading it over and over again i managed to get it working, i shall leave the code here in case that somebody cares to use it, for similar cases

```
fig = who('A*')
x = who('B*')
y = who('B*')
a = input(' Give numbers of files A...');

for i=1:a;
  x_numbers{i}=eval(u10{i});
  y_numbers{i}=eval(v10{i});
[nx,ny]= size(A);
xx=1:1:ny; 
yy=1:1:nx; 

eval(['contourf((xx),(yy),' fig{i} ')']);
colorbar;
hold on;
delta = 8;
quiver(xx(1:delta:end),yy(1:delta:end),x_numbers{i}(1:delta:end,1:delta:end),y_numbers{i}(1:delta:end,1:delta:end),1)
hold off;
drawnow;    
pause(2);    
end
```

hope it will help somebody with the same issues